# Uninstall OpenCV 3 Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

I have installed OpenCV 3.0 on my MacBook pro with Yosemite.
Unfortunately, after the installation, I realized that I needed the version 2.4.9 of OpenCV since I'm going to use some libraries that are not already supported by version 3.0.

How can I completely remove the 3.0 version? Is it enough to delete the OpenCV folder?

Comment: How did you install it ? Did you use Homebrew or another package manager, or did you just build it from scratch ?

Comment: I followed this guide http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/10/howto-install-build-and-use-opencv-macosx-10-10/ using cmake

Comment: You'll probably need to manually delete all the OpenCV includes, libraries, etc. For OpenCV 2.4.9 installation I recommend you use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) (`sudo brew install opencv`).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: remove OpenCV version 3 or higher

```
>> pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python //do this if you installed opencv-contrib-python
```

OR

```
>> pip uninstall opencv-python // do this if this is your first time
```

Step 2: download OpenCV version 2.4.9 from [Github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/tag/2.4.9) and save it to your local computer.

Step 3: go to the folder wherever you downloaded, then install OpenCV 2.4.9

You are all set.